# greater/less than time in columns

Tags: vba

if column K is E then column W should be less then 72:00:00 or 72 hrs code below is not working or gives me 'runtime error 13' pls help

```
Sub UpdateData12()
Dim c As Range, vK, vW
   Dim lr As Long
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
   lr = ws.Range("K" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For Each c In ws.Range("K2:K" & lr)
        vK = c.Value
        vW = c.Offset(0, 12).Value
        
        If vK = "E" And vW > TimeValue("72:30:00") Then
            MsgBox "Mismatch error at " & c.Address
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: `TimeValue` cannot accept a value greater than or equal to 24 hours. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function

Comment: `If vK = "E" And vW > 3 Then`

Comment: @braX is there better solution ?

Comment: I'd go with Scott's suggestion.

Comment: @ScottCraner when i use that it picks 11:09:01 as error which is not correct as its less then 72:00:00 hrs or 3 days

Comment: Then your time has a date component.

Comment: change your message to `MsgBox "Mismatch error at " & c.Address & "/" & format(vW,"dd hh:mm:ss")`

Comment: Also the "time" may be a string that looks like a date/time.  If so it would also be greater than `3`.  You can try: `If vK = "E" And cdbl(vW) > 3 Then`

Comment: Also make sure the value is actually a time and not a number that has been formatted to add the `:` like `00:00:00` which would make `110901` appear as `11:09:01` in the cell but the value would be the `110901` which is also greater than `3`

Comment: @ScottCraner If vK = "E" And cdbl(vW) > 3 Then  gave me run error its in 'General' format in the sheet

Comment: @ScottCraner not sure if it helps but numbers are far left of the cell and if i was to change any of the numbers in the cell it goes to the far right side of the cell

Comment: Then they are text and not true times.  Go with the `If vK = "E" And cdbl(application.trim(vW)) > 3 Then`

Comment: @ScottCraner iam still getting 'run time error 13' should i be setting any variables or calling anything in the start of the code?